# Using native Chrome DevTools UI in extension

Tags: google-chrome, user-interface, google-chrome-devtools, stylesheet

How can I use native UI DevTools componets (tabs, buttons, etc) in my Chrome DevTools extension?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no DevTools API for that, mostly to keep the API surface small and minimize compatibility concerns when DevTools UI changes. However, with DevTools being open source, there's little that prevents you from copying DevTools controls to your extension.